# When was the first known international call between two heads of state or government?

Tags: communication, modern

A number of international phone connections were established a little before or just after 1900:

- [Paris - Brussels](http://whitepages.fr/history/) phone line in 1886
- [England - France](http://home.bt.com/news/bt-life/history-of-bt/april-1-1891-first-cross-channel-telephone-cable-laid-between-england-and-france-11364049095453) cross-Channel telephone cable in 1891
- [Britain - Belgium](http://www.britishtelephones.com/histuk.htm) telephone service in 1903

Prior to these, the first ever international call was apparently made in 1881 ([New Brunswick, Canada - Maine, USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_telephone)).

With President Rutherford B. Hayes installing the [White House's first telephone](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/hayes-has-first-phone-installed-in-white-house) in 1877 and British Prime Minister William Gladstone doing likewise at [10 Downing Street in around 1884](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofBritain/The-History-of-10-Downing-Street/), at least two world leaders saw the potential for rapid communication early on. William McKinley (1897 - 1901) was also keen on the new gadget, being the [first to use it for a US presidential campaign](https://timeline.com/us-president-firsts-e90bbfc72743).

As the [first transatlantic call](https://www.history.com/speeches/first-transatlantic-telephone-call) was not possible until January 1927, these leaders would obviously not have been able to talk to each other but there were other (early) possibilities, most obviously perhaps in Europe. One or more calls between, for example, the British and French leaders during World War I seems a distinct possibility but I haven't been able to find any evidence.

[Churchill and Roosevelt](https://www.americanheritage.com/content/churchill-roosevelt-forgeries) were phoning each other even before Churchill became Prime Minister in May 1940, but this was 50 years after the first international phone lines were laid down, and more than ten years after transatlantic calls started. There were several major events (not least World War I) during these years and thus potentially plenty of reasons for leaders to want to communicate quickly and personally.

**When was the first (known) time the leaders of two countries *spoke* to each other, either by [radiotelephone](http://w2pa.net/HRH/radiotelephone/) or telephone?**

*Note: I'm only interested in **spoken communication**. In countries with a monarchy, either the monarch or the prime minister, chancellor,  etc. (i.e. Head of Government) would be acceptable as a 'leader' for the purposes of this question. A governor general or representative of a dominion or colony would be of secondary interest.*

Comment: Just to be sure, I assume you mean that the telegraph (or anything without voice reproduction) does not count, but "etc" would include people like the Governor-general of Canada, who technically is just a representative of the British monarch?

Comment: @Spencer Edited. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: ccording to the [Smithsonian Magazine](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/how-us-presidents-made-contact-foreign-leaders-180961338/) the first time a US President made called a foreign leader was when Coolidge called Alfonso III of Spain in around 1929.  But presumably leaders in Europe talked to each other before that.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Maybe worth posting as an answer if there are any more details. That may well be the first transatlantic one.

Comment: @Lars Bosteen - Your title mentions heads of state but you say: "For 'leaders' or 'heads of state' in countries with a monarchy, either the monarch or the prime minister, chancellor, e.t.c. would be acceptable for the purposes of this question".   A head of state is the sovereign or the most prestigious official, a head of government is the leader of the government.  Prime ministers are usually heads of government but almost never heads of state.  Your terms need defining.

Comment: @MAGolding Trying to avoid a clumsy main question but I guess you're right, it needs editing. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @JMS. If StevenBurnap does not write up, would be good to undelete as your post is the kind of thing I'm looking for (first transatlantic) and is well worth an upvote. Still hoping for something within Europe before that though...

Answer (score 7):

### First Presidential Call to a foreign leader

[image]
**President Coolidge conducts the first transatlantic phone call with a foreign leader, the King of Spain in 1927 (Library of Congress)**

> [Smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/how-us-presidents-made-contact-foreign-leaders-180961338/)
>   The first official transatlantic phone call happened on **January 7, 1927**, between New York and London. A year and a half later **(June of 1928 ?)**, Calvin Coolidge became the first president to connect with a foreign official in Europe, Alfonso III of Spain.
>
> After thanking the king for Spain’s support of the Kellog-Briand Pact, an international treaty meant to prevent the use of war as a method for resolving disputes, Coolidge launched into a soliloquy on the value of the new technological wonder:
>
> **[First off planet phone call 1969](http://www.specialtyansweringservice.net/top-13-famous-phone-calls/)**
>   In 1969, Buzz Aldrin and Neil Armstrong set foot on the moon, and soon after their moon shoes touched the lunar surface, they received a phone call from the President of the United States, Richard Nixon. “Hello Neil and Buzz, I am talking to you by telephone from the Oval Room at the White House, and this certainly has to be the most historic telephone call ever made from the White House.”
>
> **[1878, Queen victoria's first Call](http://www.britishtelephones.com/histuk.htm)**
>   Bell demonstrated the telephone to Queen Victoria on 14 January 1878 at Osborne House on the Isle of Wight with calls to London, Cowes and Southampton. These were the first long-distance calls in the UK.

.

> [1879 British thoughts on the Telephone](http://www.britishtelephones.com/histuk.htm)
>   This year, Mr. William Preece (later Sir William Preece) of the Post Office Engineering staff, when asked whether the telephone would be an instrument of the future which would be largely taken up by the public, replied “I think not”. Questioned further he said “I fancy the descriptions we get of its use in America are a little exaggerated; but there are conditions in America which necessitate the use of instruments of this kind more than here. Here we have a superabundance of messengers, errand boys, and things of that kind.”

.

> **[April 1, 1891: First cross-Channel telephone cable between England and France opened to the public](http://home.bt.com/news/bt-life/history-of-bt/april-1-1891-first-cross-channel-telephone-cable-laid-between-england-and-france-11364049095453)**
>
> - (Available only between )specially-equipped booths in London and Paris.
> - (Used) mostly by the London and Paris stock exchanges, journalists and commercial organizations.
> - it could enable only two simultaneous calls at one time